# Escape pipe character in variable in case statement

Tags: bash

mighty all,
This code

```
hst="hostname-m-0"
var1="*-m-*"
case $hst in
  $var1)
    echo "yes"
esac
```

works fine.
But this one

```
hst="hostname-m-0"
var1="*-m|*-m-0"
case $hst in
  $var1)
    echo "yes"
esac
```

does not work.
I tried to change quotes type, add them in case, escape all characters in variable - no luck.
Looks like trouble is in pipe character in variable in case statement.
Is there any way to escape it?

Comment: Since parsing happens before variable expansion, this case statement will always be executed as `case WORD in PATTERN) COMMANDS ;;esac` no matter what the variables contain. There is therefore no way to modify your variables to make it execute as `PATTERN | PATTERN )` instead. The accepted answer instead works by specifying a single pattern that matches both strings (the `|` in extglob is unrelated to `|` in `case`, just like both are unrelated to `|` in pipelines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use extended globbing for this:

```
shopt -s extglob

hst="hostname-m-0"
var1="*-m@(|-0)"

case $hst in
  $var1)
    echo "yes"
esac
```

Comment: You could just write `*-m?(-0)` here, since you don't have two non-empty alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the case-statement in eval works.

```
set -x
eval "case $hst in $var1) echo "yes" ;; *) echo "no" ;;esac"
+ eval 'case hostname-m-0 in *-m|*-m-0) echo yes ;; *) echo no ;;esac'
++ case hostname-m-0 in
++ echo yes
yes
case $hst in $var1) echo "yes" ;; *) echo "no" ;;esac
+ case $hst in
+ echo no
no
```