# How do I use $variable) in case shell script

Tags: bash, shell, case, sh

I have a command that produces the a|b|c|d|e output and stores it in valid_names.

In the script bellow, instead of $valid_names if I put the following, it works.

```
a|b|c|d|e)
```

But none of the these work:

```
$valid_names)
"$valid_names")
$(printf $valid_names))
```

Please help:

```
#!/bin/sh

valid_names=a|b|c|d|e
printf "Enter name to check: "
while :
do
  read NAME
  case $NAME in
    $valid_names)
      break
      ;;
    *)
      printf "Valid names are $valid_names, enter a valid name: "
  esac
done
```

Comment: Why do you want to use this approach? `valid_names='^(a|b|c|d|e)$'; [[ $NAME =~ $valid_names ]]` would have no problems. Similarly, `declare -A valid_names=( [a]=1 [b]=1 [c]=1 [d]=1 [e]=1 ); [[ ${valid_names[$NAME]} ]]` would be fine. And there are several other ways to check list membership (which don't use/involve `case`) which we already have covered in the knowledge base.

Comment: Also, we had almost identical question just earlier this morning -- is this a homework assignment given to several people at once? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703575/escape-pipe-character-in-variable-in-case-statement

Comment: ...to apply the answer given there, `shopt -s extglob`, and `valid_names='@(a|b|c|d|e)'` will do, as documented at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern